# Is there a native R syntax to extract rows of an array?

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, subset, tensor

Imagine I have an array in R with N dimensions (a matrix would be an array with 2 dimensions) and I want to select the rows from 1 to n of my array. I was wondering if there was a syntax to do this in R without knowing the number of dimensions.
Indeed, I can do

```
x = matrix(0, nrow = 10, ncol = 2)
x[1:5, ] # to take the 5 first rows of a matrix

x = array(0, dim = c(10, 2, 3))
x[1:5, , ] # to take the 5 first rows of a 3D array
```

So far I haven't found a way to use this kind of writing to extract rows of an array without knowing its number of dimensions (obviously if I knew the number of dimensions I would just have to put as many commas as needed). The following snippet works but does not seem to be the most native way to do it:

```
x = array(0, dim = c(10, 2, 3, 4)
apply(x, 2:length(dim(x)), function(y) y[1:5])
```

Is there a more R way to achieve this?

Comment: The R comment character is `#` not `//`. I've edited the question with this correction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your apply solution is the best, actually.

```
apply(x, 2:length(dim(x)), `[`, 1:5)
```

or even better as @RuiBarradas pointed out (please vote his comment too!):

```
apply(x, -1, `[`, 1:5)
```

Coming from Lisp, I can say, that R is very lispy.
And the `apply` solution is a very lispy solution.
And therefore it is very R-ish (a solution following the functional programming paradigm).

Comment: It's simpler to *remove* the target `MARGIN`: `apply(x, MARGIN = -1, '[', 1:5)` and can be made more general purpose. +1.

Comment: You're welcome, @GFabien! The problem actually is, the empty values in `x[1:5, , ]`, which one can in R always write as `\`x\`(1:5, , )`, actually would be: `\`x\`(1:5, 1:dim(x)[2], 1:dim(x)[3])`. to build this rest of the argument list generically is always more complicated in code than the `apply` solution.

Comment: @RuiBarradas that's elegant! I will upvote your comment when I will be able to. Just for the record I add here that if we apply this on another dimension it will permute dimensions of the array so one must be careful about that.

Comment: @GFabien I don't understand what you mean by to permute, the following on the 3rd dim works as expected: `apply(x, MARGIN = -3, '[', 1:2)`. The problem I'm seeing is with the 2nd dim, the argument `drop` doesn't work as (I) expected: `apply(x, MARGIN = -2, '[', 1, drop = FALSE)`.

Comment: I was seeing the operation as a way to subset the original array by selecting only a few elements on a given mode and leaving the other ones untouched (for example taking the five first rows is selecting elements of the first mode). Therefore, I would expect `apply(x, MARGIN = -3, '[', 1:2)` to return x but with third dimension being now of length 2, i.e. `x[, , 1:2]` for 3D array. And indeed it works but the modes are permuted. To get what I was expected, you can do something like `aperm(apply(x, -3, "[", 1:2), c(2, 3, 1))` to match `x[, , 1:2]`. (It works also for the 2nd dim.)

Answer (score 3):

Function `slice.index()` is easily overlooked (as I know to my cost! see  `magic::arow()`)  but can be useful in this case:

```
x <- array(runif(60), dim = c(10, 2, 3))
array(x[slice.index(x,1) %in% 1:5],c(5,dim(x)[-1]))
```

HTH, Robin